# Access validation error message custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<form-input label="Product Name" required name="name" model="ProdEdit.product.title"></form-input>

App.directive('formInput', function($timeout) {
    var template = '<div class="form-group">'+
    '<label for="{{id}}">{{label}}</label>'+
    '<input type="text" required name="{{name}}" class="form-control" ng-model="model" id="{{id}}" placeholder="Enter {{label}}">'+
    '<div ng-messages="myForm.name.$error" class="text-danger"></div>'+
'<span ng-message="required" >This is mandatory</span>'+
    '</div>';
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: "^ngMessages",
      template: template,
      scope: {
        label: "@",
        model: "=",
        name: "@",
        required : "&"
      },
      replace: true
    };
  })
```

I created a **form input directive** like above. Now I want to show error message in span. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Did you  facing any error

Comment: no, I am not facing any error and also any validation messages.

Comment: What error message  you want to show there?

Comment: required validation error message.!!